# TFS - Workspace deleted with pending edits

Tags: tfs

I had edits on my local machine which had it's own workspace. The machine then crashed. Luckily I was able to recover the edits from the harddrive and place them on my new machine. The TFS admin deleted my old workspace while there were still pending edits associated with it. How can I remove the edits from that deleted workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, deleting a workspace will also undo any pending edits.  If that's not the case, someone with administrative permissions could use the TFS Power Tools, go into source explorer, select those items that are still pended, and "undo" the changes.

The TFS Power Tools for TFS 2008 can be found here:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fbd14eea-781f-45a1-8c46-9f6ba2f68bf0&DisplayLang=en

Comment: Didn't know about power tools. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For clarification in TFS 2010 after you have installed the power tools, do a context menu on the source control directory you want to start from. Then choose "Find in Source Control" > "Status". Enter your search criteria. From the results list you can select appropriate files and then context menu and "Undo".